# So i have this bookmarklet but i dont like the position of the window. How could i make it in the bottom left corner, rather than the top right?

Tags: javascript, html, bookmarklet

This is the code, and i literally just copied and pasted the code from a website.  It is a code that lets me view other websites while on a website in a little window.  But im dumb and dont know how to reposition it.

`javascript:((function()%7Bvar a,b,c;c="https://www.bing.com/?safe=active&ssui=on",b=document.createElement("iframe"),b.setAttribute("src",c),b.setAttribute("id","rusic-modal"),b.setAttribute("style","position: fixed; z-index: 999999; width: 600px; height: 400px; right: 10px; top: 10px; border: 5px solid #8834af; overflow: hidden; background-color: #fff;"),a=document.getElementsByTagName("body")%5B0%5D,a.appendChild(b)%7D)).call(this)`

Comment: No. I can't even read your code. It's not formatted at all. Please start with [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Your code is required to be formatted for a human, not minified. It doesn't matter if this is a bookmarklet, you must provide human-readable code in your questions for your questions to be on-topic here.

Comment: @meagar i will work on my question asking, im new to Stack Overflow, so I'm not used to the way the community does things, plus, i really dont know anything about coding, im still in high school, taking terrible coding classes, cause my school's computer classes suck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where you have "top", replace with "bottom". Where you have "right", replace with left

So on the line with:

```
right: 10px; top: 10px; border: 5px; ...
```

Do

```
left: 10px; bottom: 10px; border: 5px; ...
```